# RTL support to custom editext for drawable left

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-canvas, android-custom-view, right-to-left

I have an edittext having an image as drawable left with a non-editable prefixed editext but now i wanted to make it to support rtl. Despite my effort I am not able to support rtl.

My Custom class is as follows,

```
public class PrefixedEditText extends TextInputEditText {

private String mPrefix = "+"; // can be hardcoded for demo purposes
private Rect mPrefixRect = new Rect(); // actual prefix size

public PrefixedEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    getPaint().getTextBounds(mPrefix, 0, mPrefix.length(), mPrefixRect);
    mPrefixRect.right += getPaint().measureText(" "); // add some offset

    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawText(mPrefix, super.getCompoundPaddingLeft(), getBaseline(), getPaint());
}

@Override
public int getCompoundPaddingLeft() {
    return super.getCompoundPaddingLeft() + mPrefixRect.width();
}

}
```

My xml call of this class is as follows,

```
<cl.dd.ui.PrefixedEditText
                    style="@style/edittext"
                    android:id="@+id/etCode"
                    android:maxLength="3"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon_phone_number"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/icon_phone_number"
                    android:minWidth="@dimen/dim_img_width"
                    android:hint="@string/s_login_code"
                    android:tag="@string/s_login_country_code"
                    android:inputType="number"/>
```

Comment: Did you try this on API 17+ or lower?

Comment: yes but is not working. and currently ltesting it on  marshmellow..it is good with english but when the app is openedin arabic mode, the prefix didn't appear.

Comment: try `drawableEnd` or `drawableRight` and see if it changes automatically

Comment: you are not getting the quesion buddy, it alearady have a drawable left or start but i added a non-editable prefix with this that is not changing with rtl

Comment: I'm going to ask this one last time, did you try what I said above? Usually it chooses which layout it has and it switches.

Comment: And you might need to add `android:autoMirrored = "true"` to your vector asset

Comment: i have done all the above mentioned steps..but no effect

Comment: I just tried implementing RTL in my app. You're right. it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve the prefixed edit text with locale support just create a custom Edit Text and Draw the prefix as a drawable.

Refer the code snippet below:

```
    /**
     * Custom EditText that displays a fixed prefix in line with the text.
     * The trick here is to draw the prefix as a drawable and attach it via
     * setCompoundDrawables().
     */

    public class PrefixEditText extends AppCompatEditText {

        private ColorStateList mPrefixTextColor;

        public PrefixEditText(Context context) {
            this(context, null);
        }

        public PrefixEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            this(context, attrs, android.R.attr.editTextStyle);
        }

        public PrefixEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyle);
            mPrefixTextColor = getTextColors();
        }

        public void setPrefix(String prefix) {
            if (Locale.getDefault().getLanguage().equalsIgnoreCase("en"))
                setCompoundDrawables(new TextDrawable(prefix + " "), null, null, null);
            else if (Locale.getDefault().getLanguage().equalsIgnoreCase("ar"))
                setCompoundDrawables(null, null, new TextDrawable(" " + prefix), null);
        }

        public void setPrefixTextColor(int color) {
            mPrefixTextColor = ColorStateList.valueOf(color);
        }

        private class TextDrawable extends Drawable {
            private String mText = "";

            TextDrawable(String text) {
                mText = text;
                setBounds(0, 0, (int) getPaint().measureText(mText) + 3, (int) getTextSize());
            }

            @Override
            public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
                Paint paint = getPaint();
                paint.setColor(mPrefixTextColor.getColorForState(getDrawableState(), 0));
                int lineBaseline = getLineBounds(0, null);
                canvas.drawText(mText, 0, canvas.getClipBounds().top + lineBaseline, paint);
            }

            @Override
            public void setAlpha(int alpha) {/* Not supported */}

            @Override
            public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter colorFilter) {/* Not supported */}

            @Override
            public int getOpacity() {
                return 1;
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You would need to make sure that `supportsRtl` is set to true in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<application
    ...
    android:supportsRtl="true">
```

And set the `layoutDirection` to `locale`, `inherit` or `rtl` in your layout xml if you are targeting SDK 17+

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layoutDirection="locale">
```

If your target SDK is below 17, you would have to create another res directory like `layout-ldrtl` or `values-ldrtl` and maybe send an rtl flag to your custom view.

Comment: How are you changing the device locale, what is your testing setup?
I tried on Android 5 emulator and Android N Nexus 6P with Arabic and it was working fine.

Comment: For debugging purposes try forcing you android:layoutDirection to rtl and see if it works

Comment: by going through settings, langauge & input

Comment: Are you sure you device's locale has changed, can you check an app like Inbox or Gmail and see if the language and layout has been updated. Can you also please try forcing the layoutDirection to rtl and let me know if it works or not

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I can suggest.

Instead of extending `TextInputEditText`, create a custom view based on a layout.

The layout can be something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content">

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/prefixTextView"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentStart="true />

     <EditText
         android:id="@+id/editText"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"     
         android:layout_toEndOf="@id/prefixTextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then, you can create a custom view, extending `RelativeLayout` with this layout. It will adapt to language direction changes.

There are a few drawbacks - the resulting View won't be in the `EditText` class hierarchy, and using it in a lot of places can end up hurting the UI performance, since it introduces nested layouts, but at least the RTL part will be OK.

Comment: anyway thanks i know, how to do this with xml but i wanted to do it with canvas.

Answer (score 0):

**To achieve RTL just put drawableStart instead of drawableLeft.
Like this :**

```
<cl.dd.ui.PrefixedEditText
                    style="@style/edittext"
                    android:id="@+id/etCode"
                    android:maxLength="3"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/icon_phone_number"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/icon_phone_number"
                    android:minWidth="@dimen/dim_img_width"
                    android:hint="@string/s_login_code"
                    android:tag="@string/s_login_country_code"
                    android:inputType="number"/>
```

This will do the trick.