# How does rtl work with custom view or canvas in Android

Tags: android, canvas, android-custom-view, right-to-left

I just wanted to know, how does Android work with custom view canvas in RTL mode. As with this example, [question link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38503081/rtl-support-to-custom-editext-for-drawable-left).

It works great with english locale but when locale is changed to arabic, its text(+) disappears.

So I don't want an answer, I basically want to know how RTL canvas works.